# - laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev]

Tags: php, laravel, composer

estoy intentado crear un proyecto laravel, pero al ejecutar el comando "composer create-project laravel/laravel aprendiendo-laravel" como lo indica la documentacion, me sale el siguiente error:

```
 "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1

```
- laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.

- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.12 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.12.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
```

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:"

ya descomente "extension=fileinfo" en php.ini y no funciona.

La carpeta aprendiendo-laravel que intento crear si se crea pero no la carpeta vendor.

Ya hice composer install y composer update.

php -v 8.0.0

Composer version 2.0.8

laravel/laravel (v8.5.7)

Que puedo hacer para solucionarlo.

Gracias

Answer (score 9):

Ya lo pude solucionar y les comparto para los que les pase lo mismo que a mi.

efectivamente lo que hay que hacer es des comentar la extensión "extension=fileinfo" en el archivo php.ini desde la carpeta de origen. El problema radicaba en que al archivo hay que otorgarle los permisos de administrador para poder ejecutar los cambios, de lo contrario, al momento de quitarle el ";" y guardar, el archivo no va a ejecutar los cambios dejando la extensión nuevamente comentado.

Para otorgar dichos permisos hay que hacer lo siguiente:
Nota:Esto para windows 10.

1. se ubica en el archivo a otorgar el permiso "c:/xampp/php/php.ini"
2. da click derecho sobre el archivo y click en propiedades.
3. seguridad.
4. click en el boton Editar.
5. da click sobre cada uno de los nombres de grupos o usuarios y en la parte de abajo donde dice Permisos de usuarios autenticados, ponen chulo donde dice control total.

De esta manera se otorga permiso y ahora si queda guardado los cambios sobre el archivo.

Espero les sirva.