# ¿Como solucionar este error al crear un proyecto laravel?

Tags: laravel

Al crear un proyecto me sale el siguiente error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1

    - laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.17.1] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.15.1].
    - league/flysystem[3.3.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.13.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.15.0, ..., 3.15.1] require league/flysystem-local ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-local[3.15.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.13.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - league/flysystem-local 3.15.0 require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.10.0, ..., v10.17.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\Program Files\php-8.2.9\php.ini

You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

Comment: Que version de php tienes?

Comment: Bienvenido a [stack overflow español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)(es). Tu pregunta no cumple con unos de los requisitos de este sitio(Que este escrita en español) sino quieres que termine cerrada y mas gente pueda responder(Yo vengo a stack overflow es porque no entiendo el ingles) recomiendo que la edites y la traduzcas a español. O prueba preguntar en [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: ingresa php -v y dinos que numero te sale

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. laravel 9](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582393/your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set-of-packages-larav)

Comment: ¿O esto? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/laravel-frameworkv8-12-0-8-x-dev-require-league-flysystem-1-1-sati